# Algorithm - Shortest path between two points in a 3D grid with different weights for faces, edges and vertices

Tags: algorithm, 3d, coordinates, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

I wish to find the shortest path between two coordinates (say, (0,0,0) and (p,q,r)) in a 3D space where going from (x,y,z) to (x+1,y,z), (z,y+1,z) or (x,y,z+1) costs some cost A, going from (x,y,z) to (x+1,y+1,z), (x+1,y,z+1) or (x,y+1,z+1) costs some cost B and going from (x,y,z) to (x+1,y+1,z+1) costs some cost C.

One way I thought of solving this problem was by running a breadth-first search. This would require **O(XYZ)** time.
I was wondering if the problem could be solved in **O(1)** time.

I made some headway by picturing each move as a piece of a stack of the form (1,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,1,1). Due to commutativity of these stack pieces, we can move them around and merge or split the pieces into each other depending on the values of A, B, and C. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Edit: A, B and C are constant across the whole grid but there are no assumptions surrounding their inequality.

Comment: [Dijkstra's?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

Comment: Are A, B and C always the same? If so, I don't see why you wouldn't go for the maximum number of "C moves", then the maximum number of "B moves", and then the rest of "A moves". Assuming C < 3A, C < A+B, and B < 2A.

Comment: Are these A,B,C values constant across the whole grid, or do they vary?  Maybe there'd be some analytical way to solve this in O(1) in the former case, but it's difficult to see how you'd do so in the latter case (as presumably you'd need to inspect a varying number of elements).

Comment: Yes, A, B and C are constant across the whole grid. Also there are no assumptions surrounding their inequalities.

Comment: Well if (for example) B > 2A, you would never opt to travel diagonally across a face (vs. travelling along two edges).  Similar logic applies to the other two inequalities that Nelxiost mentioned.  So the first thing you should do is check those inequalities, to simplify the solution space.